# (Aquatic gastropod) Physae identification

Tags: species-identification, molluscs

I need help to identify a physa.
What are the identification keys to make the difference between:

[image: physa fontinalis] **physa fontinalis**,

[image: physa marmorata]
**physa marmorata**

[image: physa acuta], **physa acuta** (syn. Physella acuta)

The difference that can been seen with the eyes, no microscope, and except their biotope? (As they are in my house, not in their biotope)

differences or identification criteriae? What are the right organs to check of the difference in eggs, etc.

There is a variability of color in snails, and a variability of sizes. One specimen in some conditions can be much bigger or smaller than the average, so it's very difficult to identify them.

Some aquatic naturalist here?

Important remark: I don't guarantee the pictures are accurate, the site posting the picture may have confused physae!

I got physae from a vendor, some have a pale body and a more yellowish or partially yellowish shell, some have the tip ot the antennae dark, and have a dark shell and a dark body. The vendor had them together, and it seems they interbreed, but I'm not sure if it's only one ssp or 2. I see nowhere color mutation of physae on the internet.